# Django Session Not Set using CROS

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.x

i am having problem with setting up session for CROS request. i have also used the cros header repo.

this is my cross origin header setting

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'Cookie',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken','x-requested-with'
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=True

CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'.*'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost',
    '192.168.1.6',
    '127.0.0.1',
)
```

and i am setting up the session using

`request.session['device'] = 'WEB'`

`request.session['user'] = {'current_user': username, 'token': 'token'}`

and set-cookie is not sent by django server to front-end server on authentication request, but as of for postman all this is working fine.